# Problem with limit proof

Tags: limits

I have problem with proof: If $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|}<1$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n}|=0$

Can anyone give me a hint how should a proof look?

One more thing, solving $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$ I get a hint to use an inequality $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{n^n}< \frac{1}{n}$ but I don't know how to show this inequality hold, I tried using induction but it didn't work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Choose $r<1$ with $r>\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{|a_{n+1}|\over|a_n|}$. There is an $N$ so that $|a_{n+1}|< r|a_n|$ for all $n\ge N$. Show, inductively, that $|a_{N+k}|< r^k|a_N|$ for all $k>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|} =q<1 $ and let $\varepsilon <1-q .$ There exist $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ we have $\frac{|a_{m+k+1}|}{|a_{m+k}|} <q+\varepsilon$ hence $$|a_{m+k+1} |<(q+\varepsilon )^{k+1} |a_{m} |$$ thus $$\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n |=\lim_{k \to \infty}|a_{m+k+1} | =0.$$

Comment: Yes, I edit. Now is Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use induction to prove if $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|}=\epsilon$ then at some large k $|a_n|\approx|a_k|\epsilon^{n-k} \rightarrow 0$

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)<\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: What is $a_n$ in the second part of your answer, where you have $n!/n^n$?

Comment: The idea is that you don't need any sort of ratio? If it's bounded by $0$ and $1/n$ it converges to $0$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_{n}\rvert}=L<1$ then for large enough $N$ we can say that $\frac{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_{n}\rvert}<L+\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ where $\epsilon>0$ is chosen so that $L+\epsilon<1$. Then for all $m> N$ we can say that:

$$\lvert a_{m}\rvert=\frac{\lvert a_{m}\rvert}{\lvert a_{m-1}\rvert}\cdot...\cdot\frac{\lvert a_{N+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_{N}\rvert}\cdot\lvert a_{N}\rvert<a_{N}(L+\epsilon)^{m-N}$$

you should be able to finish up the rest and put more detail to the answer. For you second question notice that:

$\frac{n!}{n^{n}}=\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot...\cdot\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{n}$

since $\frac{m}{n}\le1$ when $m\le n$.

Comment: It should be $a_N(L+\epsilon)^{m-N}$...

Comment: Thank you for catching that.